# How to find icons for app bar in metro windows 8?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How to find icons for app bar in metro windows 8 ? And how can i add custom icons ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default application bar styles use the font Segoe UI Symbol for it's icons, you can use the program Character Map installed with Windows to browse the icons it provides.

As well as Metro Studio that eibhrum mentioned you can find more at the [Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/) and the [Xaml Project](http://www.thexamlproject.com).

Edit: Also want to mention the fantastic [Modern UI Icons](http://modernuiicons.com).

Comment: You can look at the darkui.css and lightui.css files in the WinJS library - look for how win-backbutton is styled.  And as Nigel suggests, looking at Segoe UI Symbol in Charmap is a good way to find icons that work for you.

Comment: +1 for http://www.TheXamlProject.com  :)

Comment: +1 for the simple use of Charmap for Segoe UI Symbol. Solved my case!
And I don't think this is off topic. Icon retarded programmers like me, find this post really useful

Answer (score 4):

[Syncfusion Metro Studio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) has a collection of over 600 Metro-style icon templates that can be easily customized to create thousands of unique Metro icons.

Comment: I like them but as a new wpf person getting to a tutorial on how to actually use their xaml library output is challenging.

Answer (score 4):

Document from MSDN: [WinJS.UI.AppBarIcon enumeration (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770557.aspx)

All available systems icons are list there.

To add custom icons, you can download samples from MSDN:

- [HTML AppBar control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-bar-sample-a57eeae9)
- [XAML AppBar control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-AppBar-control-sample-2aa1cbb4)

Answer (score 1):

Someone compiled a list of built-in appbar icons here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/adamkinney/6952800759/sizes/o/in/photostream/

I think this is your best option most of the time, since they're available in every installation, and of the highest quality.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Templarian/WindowsIcons

all the appbar icons for windows phone 8 in given link. Download the Zip.file from there.